# SSH protocol with PIC18

Tags: ssh, pic, ethernet, tcp

We are the company ELINAP (Electronics and Applied Computing), and we are working on the development of programs to comply with the TS13 149 standard of passenger counting systems for public transport vehicles produced by us, those , are made with a microcontroller type **PIC18F87J60** (16bits). The purpose of the project is to introduce new management protocols for this standard to our ELINAP products. The standard requires security based on the **Secure Shell (SSH)** protocol, however, we had difficulty finding this protocol on the **TCP / IP stack**, so let us ask you these questions:

Is the Secure Shell (SSH) protocol implemented on the TCP / IP stack? And is it supported by the PIC18F87J60?

> ELINAP (ELECTRONIQUE ET INFORMATIQUE APPLIQUEE)
>   Rue Thiébaud, 25000
>   BESANCON, FRANCE Email: 
>   elinap@orange.fr
>   Tel: 03 81 88 71 16

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for questions about programming. This question isn’t about programming.

Comment: Good evening, I am a trainee at the company ELINAP and I am at the origin of this question. sorry to have bothered you but, it's a question of programming (network programming) using the TCP / IP stack! Our problem is to know if the SSH protocol code is well implemented, otherwise, a help would be welcome to help us to program this security protocol